# Rails API, should I pass in user_id along with the token to verify authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I have a model RememberToken that looks like this...

```
class CreateRememberTokens < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :remember_tokens do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.string :token

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and I've made a backend Rails API specifically to be accessed by an iOS app.

When the user signs up or signs in... a token is returned to the user, and this is stored in the device (the digested token). (They user can log in via iPhone, iPad, etc. The model will track multiple tokens).

However, I'm wondering if the user should stored a pair of items... the [token, user_id] pair. As you can see the model above has an index on the user reference. If there are 50,000 users with 3 tokens at once... well that's not much at all... but let's say there were millions of entries. It would speed up the process if we could first find the user_id, return those 1-4 remember_token's... and then check to see if the passed in token matches any of these.

So my question is...

**Would it be better to pass in [token, user_id] to look for active tokens, instead of just just [token]?**